# CSS: Keep element centered and another one next to it

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I would like to always keep the "Left" element next to the "Centered" element, taking into account that the "Centered" must always be centered:

[image]

Here is my code and a screenshot of how it looks at the moment:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container>div:first-child,
.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fA5858;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 15px/1 Sans-Serif;
}

.container>div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #5882FA;
  margin: 0 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>Centered</div>
</div>
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/9shor0cb/26/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do something like this with flexbox:

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}


.container .inner div:first-child,
.container .inner div:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fA5858;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 15px/1 Sans-Serif;
}

.container .inner div:first-child {
  position:absolute;
  transform:translatex(-100%)
}

.container .inner div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #5882FA;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>Centered</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be very useful, but when I implement it in mine, it doesn't work. This would be the expected result:

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/J01PBoM

Sorry for not posting this information earlier.

Comment: @iWozzming try the updated code.

Comment: HTML: https://collabedit.com/7cbkw
CSS: https://collabedit.com/72n4a

Comment: @iWozzming make a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/73kzu9yt/

Comment: name must be centered and the image to its left

Comment: @iWozzming I have modified your code. you didn't understand my answer : https://jsfiddle.net/9eabom0s/ (if you want to move the image more to the right use   `transform: translateX(calc( -100% - 8px));`